# Step over hoisting phase when debugging in VS Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, hoisting

Is there a way to skip the hoisting phase when running a debugger plugin in VS code for TypeScript and JavaScript projects? I find that I am spending too much time doing so.

Comment: `the hoisting phase` I'm not sure what's meant by this. Can you clarify?

Comment: I lacked a better term.  JavaScript passes through the entire code and sets variables to undefined and saves function declarations before executing the code. This is called hoisting. In VS Code, you get to see this part under the 'Variables' section of the left debug panel in VS Code.

Comment: I figured you were referring to hoisting, but i still don't understand what you're trying to do. Hoisting is a mental model for describing an aspect of javascript execution. It sounds like you're trying to execute code, but without hoisting, which doesn't make sense to me. Hoisting and javascript execution are not separable.

Comment: I see the mistake I made there. I meant stepping over not skipping. Editing the question now.

Comment: I knew you knew what hoisting meant.

Comment: @heretoinfinity Are you using any kind of transpiler? I don't see any execution steps when entering a scope.